# Symfony Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I just received some open project files form a customer, where I have to make some adjustments. The project is based ons Symfony Framework and in order to get the project running on my machine, I have to set up the symfony  workflow.

I already installed all necessary dev dependencies I guess and when I start my app via:

```
php bin/console server:run
```

> I get following errors: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such
>   file or directory

I read couple of threads about this error and most people recommend changing the host from "127.0.0.1" to "localhost" and vice versa.

If i enter "localhost" to be my host, I end up with the error from above.

If I put "127.0.0.1" as my host, I get "connection refused" instead of "No such file or directory"

Comment: Well, perhaps, first you should try running the server with verbose output enabled (`php bin/console server:run`), second, to me it looks like you should double-check the driver you've chosen in `database_driver`, since PDO shouldn't require presence of any files, unless you're using a socket connection.

Comment: @kix this is MySQL's error, not PDO itself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your local mysql service is running as well.
2. Check database configuration in yaml. Make sure the connection to your local mysql is correct.
3. Run

   app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

to create the database and all the tables for the project.

Let us know if anything of this works or does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding

```
parameters:
    #...
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

in the `app/parameters.yml` file.

You should also check if your `database_(name|user|password)` values are correct.